# Google App Engine map static_dir to remote url

Tags: python, google-app-engine, ftp

I have files on a remote FTP server that are accessible over web. My mate developer works with static files to build a frontend for our project - he works with JS/CSS/HTML etc. Then he uploads the files to FTP server. Now these files are accessible over web standard way. Is that possible for us to setup GAE app the way like this:

```
- url: /css
  static_dir: http://our-static-files-url.com/css
```

The purpose why we want it to do this way is that I work on the backend and create all the core accessible over web completely with AJAX/JSON. So I deploy the whole project standard way with GAE SDK. This way I don't deal with frontend files like HTML templates, CSS sheets and JavaScript files. My mate works with them and we want to work independently. So, when I add some feature to the code, I then notify my mate that I added some endpoint for his use. He makes necessary updates to his markup and JavaScript code to consume data from the endpoint I provided. What are the best practices for us to work on this?
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**NO**, you can't declare a remote `static_dir` in `app.yaml` .

What you and your friend would probably want is a remote source code repository using [git](http://git-scm.com/) or [mercurial](http://mercurial.selenic.com/); have a look to [github](https://github.com/) for a free hosting solution for example.

Comment: You are right. We have realized it will be a good solution for us. It seems it was not a perfect way I wanted to go. Thanks!